# Django 1.10 super-easy filters

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am looking for an easy way to implement a filter for my objects. A basic one. And all I could find was Django+Haystack+Solr or Elasticsearch. I do not have an experience to use Java apps. Plus ... I want to keep it simple.

The closest I could get was [django_filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/), but the docs for it are ... well not for the noob like me. Plus cant I do the same with plain Django ?? I was able to get simple search to work with no solr :) And I am able to get filters to work in admin so all the tools are there.

If anyone could guide me step, by step how to set up filter for and status from my model. 
Model

```
    class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2000
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Email", default="adress@email.com")
    STATUS = (
('A','Active'),
('U','Unactive')
        )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE, default="A")
        def _unicode_(self):
        return self.name
    def _str_(self):
        return self.name
```

My views with search working:

```
def index(request):
    #full list
    queryset_list = Contact.objects.all()
    #search
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query)|
            Q(phone__icontains=query)|
            Q(url__icontains=query)| 
            Q(email__icontains=query)| 

    #pagination
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "name" : "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
            }

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Comment: So, you're already filtering your query by the GET parameter. What do you want to filter this by?

Comment: I want to add filter option for STATUS. So potential user can get all active, unactive or all Contacts. Sounds easy ... I just need a right direction since all I could google was including this complex java solutions.

Comment: Two ways. You either do it manually, create another form field in HTML with the name "status". On form submit you will have it in request.GET. Filter your query with another Q object using it and pass it back to the context to set the form field value. Second way is actually to use Django filter which is not hard at all. I can show you.

Comment: Pretty please? It would be great if you could show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving you a minimum example, just so you read some docs in case you have some errors.

First, put your status choices into settings file, so that, just in case, you could use anywhere else.

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('A','Active'),
    ('U','Unactive')
)
```

Then you need to create a filter set, put it into `models.py` for now:

```
from django.conf import settings
import django_filters

class SearchFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=settings.STATUS_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

Then in your view:

```
def index(request):
    queryset_list = Contact.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')

    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(phone__icontains=query) |
            Q(url__icontains=query) | Q(email__icontains=query)
        )

    filtered = SearchFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset_list)
    context = {
        'filtered': filtered,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And finally in the template put this:

```
...
{{ filtered.form.status }}
...
```

Comment: At first this happened: `AssertionError: Setting 'Meta.model' without either 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' has been deprecated since 0.15.0 and is now disallowed. Add an explicit 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' to the SearchFilter class.` but I managed to get info and added `fields = ['status']`. So no more errors. Still not fully functional though - missing template I guess.

Comment: Got it to the point I have my wanted values in a drop down next to my search box. My search works. But when I pick a value from filters drop-down and click filter ... nothing happens. :( `form action="" method="get">
        {{ filtered.form.status }}
        <button type="submit">Filter</button>
    </form>`

Comment: Ok, so you already figured out that you need to add fields to Meta class you want to have filtering on :)

Comment: Nothing happens as in, the page doesn't refresh?

Comment: Yup. No action. Items are not filtered.

Comment: I think ... might be I am wrong, the context is a part of the problem. Since I used it like this: `context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "name" : "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var, 'filtered': filtered,
            }` And in index.html I iterate objects to show by `obj in object_list`. Need to figure out the way to combine filtered and object_list.

Comment: I've made it to work with this guide: [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html) Still a lot of testing and "bootstraping" to meke it user friendly. Thanks for initial help. Got me going.